# Let $S$ be the set of all subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ with size $k$. Find the number of other elements that has an intersection of size $l$ with a vertex

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be the set of subsets of size $k$ from $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Let $a$ be an element of $S$.

Determine the number of other elements of $S$ that have an intersection of size $l$ with $a$.

---

I have worked through this and found that it is (I think): $k \choose l$$(n-k)$.
Because there are $k \choose l$ choices of numbers to change and $(n-k)$ choices for each.

I also questioning my answer now because if there are $(n-k)$ choices of numbers to change each number to, some may get changed to the same number which is not allowed as the set can't have repeats.

Comment: HINT: Every such set $X$ is the disjoint union $$(X \cap a) \cup (X \setminus a)$$ hence you have to choose $l$ elements of $a$ to form the first and $k-l$ from $a^c$ to form the second.

Comment: I've made significant changes to my answer since you accepted it. I hope the explanation is even clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose $l$ elements from $a$ and $k - l$ elements from outside of $a$. Therefore the answer is

$$ {k \choose l}{n - k \choose k - l}. $$

If you do it your way it should be

$$ (n - k)^{k \choose l} $$

i.e. the product, not the sum. You are making the choices simultaneously. But this formula is still wrong for several reasons:

1. You are not replacing ${k \choose l}$ elements you are replacing $k - l$ elements so that should have been $(n - k)^{k - l}$ what you are doing with ${k \choose l}$ is choosing a distinguished set of $l$ elements (equiv. a distinguished set of $k - l$ elements). Thus you now have ${k \choose l}(n - k)^{k - l}$
2. You are doing nothing to ensure that you do not replace two or more elements by the same element. It should not be $n - k$ choices for every one of the $k - l$ vertices, it should be $n - k$ for the first, $n - k - 1$ for the second, etc. This gives ${k \choose l}(n - k)^{\underline{l - k}}$ where the underline denotes the falling product: $$x^{\underline{n}} = x(x - 1)(x - 2)\cdots(x - (n - 1))$$
3. Now you have to account for the order in which you make the replacements: it doesn't matter. Thus you finally have $${k \choose l}\frac{(n - k)^{\underline{l - k}}}{(l - k)!} = {k \choose l}{n - k \choose l - k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Fix $A\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $\#A=k$. Fix a subset $B\subseteq A$ with $\#B=\ell$ (this can be done in $\binom{k}{\ell}$ ways). Then you need to find all subsets of $C\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus A$ with $\#C=k-\ell$ (this can be done in $\binom{n-k}{k-\ell}$ ways). Considering that the collection of all $B\cup C$ are the wanted sets, the answer is
$$
\binom{k}{\ell}\binom{n-k}{k-\ell}.
$$